# Exercise of class algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A,B,C class, prove $A \cup C=B\cup C $ iff $A \bigtriangleup B \subseteq C$, where $A \bigtriangleup B  =(A\cap B^{c})\cup(B\cap A^{c})$

I could prove that $A \cup B=B\cup C $ then $A \bigtriangleup B \subseteq C$ proving that $(A\cap B^{c})\subseteq C$ and also that $(B\cap A^{c})\subseteq C$, but I have not been able to prove the other implication.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \Delta B \subseteq C$. Suppose, if possible, there is a point $x \in A\cup C$ such that $x \notin B\cup C$. Then $x \notin C$ (because if $x \in C$ then  $x \in B\cup C$). Now $x \in A\cup C$ and $x \notin C$  imply $x \in A$. If $x \notin B$ then we get $x \in A\Delta B \subseteq C$, a contradiction. Hence $x \in B$ which implies $x \in B\cup C$. But $x \notin B\cup C$. This proves that $A\cup C \subseteq B\cup C$ and the reverse inclusion is similar.